# just: error: Justfile does not contain recipes when pre-committing

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, ruff, just

I'm referencing `just` commands in custom `pre-commit` hooks. For some reason, `just` is interpreting *staged files* as *recipes*, which leads to

```
trim trailing whitespace.................................................Passed
fix end of files.........................................................Passed
check yaml...............................................................Passed
check toml...............................................................Passed
ruff (linter)............................................................Failed
- hook id: ruff-lint
- exit code: 1

error: Justfile does not contain recipes 
`folder_1/src/alembic/versions/fb4554c0e46f_first_commit.py`, 
`folder_1/src/alembic/env.py`, `folder_1/src/crud/user.py`, or `config.py`.

ruff (formatter).........................................................Failed
- hook id: ruff-format
- exit code: 1

error: Justfile does not contain recipes 
`folder_1/src/alembic/versions/fb4554c0e46f_first_commit.py`, 
`folder_1/src/alembic/env.py`, `folder_1/src/crud/user.py`, or `config.py`.
```

My project tree is as follows (at least for what pertains to the files listed within the error message):

```
|-- folder_1
    |-- src
        |-- alembic
        |   |-- env.py
        |   |-- versions
        |       |-- fb4554c0e46f_first_commit.py
        |-- crud
        |   |-- user.py
        ...
|-- folder_2
    |-- src
    ...
.pre-commit-config.yaml
config.py
justfile
poetry.lock
pyproject.toml
```

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` is as follows:

```
default_language_version:
  python: python3.10

repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0
    hooks:
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: check-toml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: ruff-lint
        name: ruff (linter)
        entry: just ruff-fix
        language: system
        types: [python]
      - id: ruff-format
        name: ruff (formatter)
        entry: just ruff-format
        language: system
        types: [python]
```

My `justfile` is as follows:

```
help:
  @just --list

install:
  @echo " Installing dependencies"
  @poetry install --with dev

install-pre-commit:
  @echo " Setting up the hooks"
  @poetry run pre-commit install

check-project:
  @echo " Checking consistency between poetry.lock and pyproject.toml"
  @poetry check --lock
  @echo " Running the hooks against all files"
  @poetry run pre-commit run --all-files

ruff:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff"
  @poetry run ruff check .

ruff-show-violations:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff and show violations"
  @poetry run ruff check --output-format="grouped" .

ruff-fix:
  @echo " Linting the project with Ruff and autofix violations (where possible)"
  @poetry run ruff check --fix .

ruff-format:
  @echo " Formatting the code with Ruff"
  @poetry run ruff format .

ruff-format-check:
  @echo " Listing files Ruff would reformat"
  @poetry run ruff format --check .

lint-and-format: ruff-fix ruff-format
```

Versions:

```
$ just --version
just 1.23.0

$ pre-commit --version
pre-commit 3.7.0
```

Can someone help with this issue? I used to work with a similar setup in different repositories and it did always work.

Eventually, substituting [`poetry run ruff check --fix .`] to [`just ruff-fix`] and [`poetry run ruff format .`] to [`just ruff-format`] into `.pre-commit-config.yaml` just :) works, but I'd like to use `just` commands.

Answer (score 0):

you've selected `types: [python]` in your configuration -- as the name says it matches python files in your repository -- and clearly not all of your `types: [python]` files are just files

you probably want to adjust your filtering by using either [`files`](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-files) or [`exclude`](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-exclude)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I get it, though. All files listed within the error message are indeed python files. Plus, the error only appears as soon as I reference entries with `just`.
Can you elaborate more on _clearly not all of your types: [python] files are just files_, please?